# Already got html-parser for BS4 : Couldn't find a tree builder ... html-parser

Tags: beautifulsoup, pip, python-3.8, html-parser

I installed beautifulsoup4 in my project's ​directory, using requirment.txt :

> requests==2.26.0
> beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
> html-parser

```
pip3 install -r requirement.txt --target='local_lib'
```

and I get this error when trying to import and run:

```
from local_lib.bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = Beautifulsoup(html, 'html.parser')


local_lib.bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html-parser. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

It works when I tried to import from bs4, not local_lib.bs4.
However, I want to use only local_lib directory for modules.

Why I get this error for my local_lib and How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it. When do import between its own modules/packages Beautifulsoup4 uses absolute import. For example:

[https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/604/bs4/builder/__init__.py#L7](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/604/bs4/builder/__init__.py#L7)

```
from bs4.element import …
```

I.e., `bs4` is required to be a top-level package, it cannot be a subpackage. To make it a subpackage you should rewrite the whole source code and make all import relative. Similar to [this pull-request](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/pull/46/files) to my project Cheetah3 sent with [the similar reason](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/pull/46#issue-694342742): "*This makes it possible to embed Cheetah in other packages…*"

Comment: Great info! Thank you. There was a method to check if the module support absolute import or not. i will try to check on that later.

Comment: Thank you! after your comment, I checked module source code and now I understand why it did not work ..